# Question labelled bad faith post without much reasoning

Tags: discussion, specific-question, close-reasons

I had posted [this question](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/70545/why-should-one-wish-to-increase-representation-of-minority-groups), it was closed with reason said that it is bad faith post. I am in disagreement with this, one of the replies hinted there maybe some underlying racism in my post, but I quickly explained that saying that race and intelligence is gene traits separately inherited. Have also given a rebbutal to the comment by mod directly underneath my post.

Could any other reason be given as a fault in my post which I may have missed or any point missing in the rebutals I have given? if there is none, could my post be reopened please?

Answer (score 10):

Please keep in mind that readers/listeners have a difficult time distinguishing between malignant 'bad faith' and honest, innocent ignorance.  In a better world people tend to extend *good faith* to speakers — giving the speaker the benefit of the doubt about problematic statements — but unfortunately the modern world has weaponized willful ignorance to such an extent that benefit-of-the-doubt is given sparingly, if at all. The onus is now on the writer to be clear in his speech.

I'm making this point specifically about this part of your question:

> The manifestation of race based differences are due to the different
> genes in people and the environment they grew up in. Taking the idea
> of affirmative action to the logical extreme, wouldn't society in the
> future have AA based on literally what genes a person has? This seems
> a bit absurd to me.
>
> On this track, would we be compromising the quality of the candidates
> in the upper position as in attempts to give equivalent gene
> reservation (sic), wouldn't we push those with worser genes (chance for
> disease, lower cognitive ability) into upper position.

Now, we could write this off as simple misunderstanding of the sciences involved and spend some time in an answer correcting the assumptions implicit in this question: e.g., the assumption that race can predict quality of performance, and thus that AA would *automatically* push inferior candidates into upper positions. But in the real world this assumption has been stated and refuted so extensively over the last hundred years or so, by so many disparate individuals, that it's difficult to believe there is good faith behind *yet another* restatement. I mean, one of the following must be true:

1. You make such statements in complete innocence, which means you've done **literally no** investigation or research, but are merely parroting the 'common knowledge' of some particular, parochial community, or...
2. You are informed an aware of the many arguments that have refuted this position, but choose to avoid them because they don't fit well within your given worldview, or...
3. You are informed an aware of the many arguments that have refuted this position, can understand and process them, but actively ignore them because they conflict with a social or political agenda that is important to you.

None of us know which of these three is true, none of us will *ever* know which of these three is true, and no statements you can make to the contrary will be believable. The mere act of making such frequently refuted assumptions (without acknowledgement of the refutations) damages your credibility. You may have intentions as pure as the driven snow for all we know, but that's between you and you on the inside of your skull. What we **see** is a recitation of some of the most problematic and pugnacious claims from centuries of dyed-in-the-wool white ethno-nationalism.

If you want us to treat you as a *morally good* author (°1), it becomes increasingly difficult to treat you as an *intelligent* author. If you want us to treat you as an *intelligent* author (°3), it becomes increasingly difficult to treat you as a *morally good* author. And the alternative in which we see you as presenting a basically decent but small-minded viewpoint (°2) isn't all that thrilling for anyone. Can you blame people for just wanting to be rid of this question?

Comment: I think there is a misunderstanding that since the previous paragraph had race that I am taking that people who are of color have bad genes. I don't see any evidence to believe that is true, so I don't have an opinion on it. I have clarified this multipile time over comments on this post and others. Not sure why it's being still brought up.

Comment: The point of re-statement, I think just because one thing has been discussed over a long time doesn't mean the information is easily digestable/  available to the common person/ should be in knowledge of them. Take for example, whole of mathematics, sciences etc. It's been there much longer than than that and conversation of that has taken place even longer, still it is not really common knowledge yet.

Comment: @Buraian: As I said, we're not mind-readers, so we don't know what you think or believe. All we know is what you *say*, and what you *said* was fairly simple and direct. Are you telling me that you don't understand why a reasonable reader would interpret your question as essentially white ethno-nationalist? If that's what you're trying to tell me then you force me (again) to wonder whether you re deeply naïve (°1) or stridently deceptive (°3). Which would you prefer I thought about you?

Comment: Or, perhaps your categorization and the criteria for it are not correct and be able to take note of something when someone has repeated that over multiple posts (including the first answer given). I've explained this multiple times in the previous comment as well.

Comment: @Buraian: I notice that you did not answer my (direct and simple) question, do I"ll assume that you either do not wish to admit that you are aware that a reasonable reader would interpret your question as essentially white ethno-nationalist, nor wish to claim excessive ignorance of that fact. You think by remaining silent the issue will go away. It won't; your silence just reinforces my point, and reinforces the fact that my 'categorization and criteria' (as you put it) are correct.Sorry, but you're going to have to own this, own way or another.

Comment: The idea suffers from the same issue that of 'star signs' in horoscope does, it tries to stereotype by forming categories considering common traits which may occur together.  Usually a person's motivation or wishes aren't as clear as your personality quiz. The question here, I've given my stance on most of these things , trying to go back from my stance and trying to conclude on other characteristics is besides the point.

Comment: @Buraian: Yeesh, what a trope... How many times have I seen someone do/say something offensive, stupid, wrong, or outright destructive, only to have them say: "I'm not the kind of person who does/says such bad things, so it didn't happen." Sorry, but it happened. If you're not the kind of person who does/says such things, admit you made a mistake and try to do better in the future. If you can't/won't do that, you'll accomplish nothing except to convince everyone that it wasn't a mistake at all, but a reflection of who you really are.

Answer (score 7):

As I wrote in the comment when I closed the question: "Politics Stack Exchange is a Q&A site, not a debate forum." As the help center article "[What topics can I ask about here](https://politics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)" says:

> Politics Stack Exchange is for objective questions about governments, policies and political processes. It is not a place to advance opinions or debate, but rather for exchanging objective information about the policies, processes, and personalities that comprise the political arena.

The question is starting with a very short question on a very controversial issue ("Should we have Affirmative Action?"). And even that question is phrased in the style of a rhetorical question which could very well be the opening paragraph of a Tucker Carlson segment on Fox News:

> Exactly, why the idea of AA to increase the representation of minority group through methods is gaining prominence? I don't

And then it continues with three paragraphs where the author gives an essay about their personal views on the issue.

In a comment you said:

> the idea of starting of a debate was not my intention.

But I can't really see a way to reply to a question phrased like this without debating the author.

And as we saw, debating you is exactly what happened in the answer that was posted before I closed the question. To which you replied by debating back. For not intending to start a debate, you were not just pretty successful at starting a debate, you were also pretty eager to continue that debate.

You further stated:

> The nature of the question/answer being felt as sharing of one's thought is inevitable on this site. As it's people who are writing question and answers and whatever is written by people inherit the biases of people.

I disagree. A proper on-topic question should be understandable without stating ones own opinions on the matter. When the question is not understandable and answerable without knowing the subjective opinions of the author, then it is not an objective questions about governments, policies and political processes.

Comment: "Exactly, why the idea of AA to increase the representation of minority group through methods is gaining prominence? I don't"
Title question  title was what reasons should one have to increase representation of minority groups?

Comment: >But I can't really see a way to reply to a question phrased like this without debating the author.

And as we saw, debating you is exactly what happened in the answer that was posted before I closed the question. To which you replied by debating back. For not intending to start a debate, you were not just pretty successful at starting a debate, you were also pretty eager to continue that debate.

I don't believe in debating for debates sake, if anyone user had linked some information contrary to the premise, I'd have changed and edited the question to be accurate.

Comment: I don't see a real issue why debating for clearing up issues in the body in itself is bad, perhaps someone referred a wrong new's source and was misinformed....

Comment: >I disagree. A proper on-topic question should be understandable without stating ones own opinions on the matter. When the question is not understandable and answerable without knowing the subjective opinions of the author, then it is not an objective questions about governments, policies and political processes.

I brought my opinion so the answerer would understand about what specific part of the issue I am asking. Also, 90% of the answers and questions in this site are opinions, what you considerd "fact based answers" are really just answers which are best to people's knowledge

Comment: Rather than the absolute truth that they found. Politics by definition is not an exact science.. there are no mathematical equations to give you what the exact correct procedure is....

Comment: "Q&A site" is too often the secondary excuse for removal, when according to given reason it's about content.

Answer (score 3):

One reason it's not so good is it starts by saying Affirmative Action is new. That's wrong by about 70 years. A simple search would have found that out. Basically, the question starts with a huge lie, less than 2 weeks after Martin Luther King day.

Later on, the question groups US blacks with Asians. That doesn't make any sense. Black people in the US are a unique category of discrimination, due to slavery. This is not a little known fact. No one thinks the KKK worked as hard against Asians, or that there was a similar anti-Asian terror group, or there were White and Colored/Asian drinking fountains. Now Chinese (who count as Asian, I assume?) had it bad, but in a similar category (but worse) as Irish or Italians and so on. Grouping "dark skinned and Asians" is so awkward that it's almost like deliberately lying about Jim Crow.

Adding your thoughts just muddies the question. You already told us you don't know anything about affirmative action. Adding way-off-base guesses doesn't improve the question -- we believe you know nothing about the topic -- you don't have to prove it.

Now we come to the part where you say that people with inferior genes shouldn't have important jobs. Searching "inferior genes" quickly takes you to "Eugenics". Searching for that brings up Wikipedia's page explaining that it's bad and was most famous in Nazi Germany. This isn't just some search trick -- a Family Feud with "inferior genes" as the clue would have that in the 100 people surveyed. So pretty much, that whole "Some thoughts I've had" section in the question could be retitled "According to Hitler", since those are the only people who talk about genes that way.

To sum up, the tone is polite, but the content, all of it, is super racist -- like what you'd find on a White Supremacist site. I hope this helps.

Comment: The novelty of AA as it being the first time is not what I suggested but the prominence of under representing. For example, it was only a few months back that Caltech finally realized Caste discrimination and I think began with AA actions related to that.

And have a look at the black lives matter thing, perhaps it may have been due to my lack of internet usage, that only became as common to see on Social media about 2-3 years back. The question was written from the POV of someone who is not a US citizen.

I don't quite understand why you must have an addition of( (contin)

Comment: " We believe you know nothing about the topic, you don't know anything about the topic" If anything it would have been more reasonable to link me sites where I could correct the mistaken thoughts, but rather I felt the logic in the answer provided was weak and tried to **jump around addressing **

Comment: The whole post was simply an attempt to understand what was going on in the mind's of others and trying to see if there is any sense even in what maybe have been said by Hitler. It is unscientific to simply dismiss arguments due to the person who said it rather than analyze and point out exact faults..

Comment: @Buraian But now you know the site doesn't work that way. If you write an offensive question with lots of wrong stuff, people don't think "awww...let me help that poor person". They say "ewww...get that horrible question out of here".

Comment: It really does degrade the quality of the site when a childish insult like the remarks on your question and comment are allowed on the site are encouraged while fact based corrections are not.

Comment: @Buraian Your original question was much more offensive than anything on this page.

Comment: I didn't know that it would be taken as such, with suggestion given, I had amended in an attempt to remove the offence material and keep only the exact question I wanted to ask in there. The concept exists independent of what may have caused people to have been triggered by it. The question I asked, if it could be answered by a person with knowledge, could convince someone to support themselves representation of minority be it blacks or Asians.

Comment: Also, suppose whatever the initial post I put was, I can't still imagine it to be justified to throw snarky remarks like this and try to raise tensions more and more. It is just devolving the conversation using meaningless powerplay. Suppose, if instead, these commentors had commented a fact contrary to the premise of the question instead of going such accusations to begin with, then there is really nothing I can say to it and I can only change my question premise. Now, am I saying all question with problematic premise should be given such considerations? (contin)

Comment: If the premise fundamentally is meaningless then within a back and forth of few comments there will be no question, or, the question will be edited into something suitable into the site.

Comment: @Buraian Alrighty. I'm not really sure what you're trying to say.